# How to set an observer on an array property in polymer element?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, observers, mutation-observers

The **history** property defined in my **sma-canvas** element:

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        history: {
            type: Array,
            value: () => {
                return [];
            },
            notify: true
        }
    };
}

static get observers() {
    return [
        '_historyChanged(history.*)'
    ];
}

_historyChanged() {
    console.log("History Changed!");
    this._redrawCanvas(this.$.canvasEl, this.history);
}
```

I'm trying to set the **history** property from another element:

```
<dom-module id="sma-create-studio">
    <template>
        <sma-canvas id="shapesCanvasEdit" history={{shapesOnCanvasEdit}}></sma-canvas>
    </template>
<dom-module>
```

...

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        shapesOnCanvasEdit: {
            type: Array,
            value: () => {
                return [];
            },
            notify: true
        }
    };
}

_selectFrame(e) {
    // this.shapesOnCanvasEdit = e.detail.frame.shapes;

    // this.shapesOnCanvasEdit.splice(0, this.shapesOnCanvasEdit.length);
    // this.shapesOnCanvasEdit.push(e.detail.frame.shapes);

    this.set('shapesOnCanvasEdit', e.detail.frame.shapes);

    // this.splice('shapesOnCanvasEdit', 0, this.shapesOnCanvasEdit.length, e.detail.frame.shapes);

    // this.splice('shapesOnCanvasEdit', 0, this.shapesOnCanvasEdit.length);
    // this.push('shapesOnCanvasEdit', e.detail.frame.shapes);

    // this.notifyPath('shapesOnCanvasEdit');
    // this.notifySpice('shapesOnCanvasEdit');
}
```

I need to call **_historyChanged** (the observer in **sma-canvas**), whenever I change the value of **shapesOnCanvasEdit**. As you can see from the last code snippet, I tried multiple ways to do that, but all in-vain.

Can anybody please help me in this regard? I have no clue, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: any reason why you're observing second level elements from your array? what would be the problem if you define your observer just like `_historyChanged(history)`?

Comment: also in the parent element it might be better to use quotes around the property, so `history="{{shapesOnCanvasEdit}}"` instead of `history={{shapesOnCanvasEdit}}`

Comment: Everything seams correctly except @mishu explained above about `quotes`.

Comment: A side note, but `_historyChanged()` and `_selectFrame(e)` should be `_historyChanged: function()` and `_selectFrame: function(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION 1**

> ```
> static get properties() {
>     return {
>       active: {
>         type: Boolean,
>         // Observer method identified by name
>         observer: '_activeChanged'
>       }
>     }
>   }
>
>   // Observer method defined as a class method
>   _activeChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
>     this.toggleClass('highlight', newValue);
>   }
> ```
>
> https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/observers#change-callbacks

From my experience in 1.93, adding a simple observer for an array updates the array if the length changes. (Change Boolean to Array in the example above.)

**SOLUTION 2**

You can observe splices:

> ```
> static get observers() {
>   return [
>     'usersAddedOrRemoved(myArray.splices)'
>   ]
> ```
>
> https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/observers#array-observation
>       }

It only fires if the array length changes. To force update, reset it array `myArray` with `this.set('myArray', [])`, if you're desperate.

**SOLUTION 3**

The truly desperate solution. Add a secondary int variable that you update every time there is a change in the array. So `_selectFrame()` should first update your array `history` and then update the integer, and both should be properties in `sma-canvas`. Set an observer on that integer variable in your `sma-canvas` element, as shown in solution 1.